# Topology Exercises Books

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am taking next semester a class on Topology and was wondering if anyone could advise me a book containing a lot of exercises WITH solutions in order to train.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fundamentals of General Topology: Problems and Exercises, Arkhangel'skii A., Ponomarev V.

Elementary topology, problem textbook,
Viro O., Ivanov O., Netsvetaev N., Kharlamov V.

The topology problem solver,
The Staff of REA

Comment: Thank you. These seem very good books based on the previews on amazon

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: The book by Viro, et al. is great. You can get a free version online which is the same as the print version but with no solutions. This isn't a big deal, because the print version doesn't have all solutions anyways.

Answer (score 6):

This one is very nice:

[Counterexamples in Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048668735X), by Steen & Seebach.

Comment: It's a great book, but I wouldn't recommend it for beginners!

Answer (score 5):

Another interesting one which illustrates lots of problems is:

> [*Schaums Outline of General Topology*](https://archive.org/details/SchaumsTheoryProblemsOfGeneralTopology) by S. Lipschutz