# Topology textbook with a solution manual

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

Does anyone know of a good topology textbook, that has a solutions manual for at least some of the problems? Older is fine; I just need to be able to check my own work.

I've researched best topology books/free topology books, but most do not have any solutions to problems provided.

Thanks for your help; hope I'm posting in right forum.

Comment: I think Bert Mendelson's intro to topology is a rudimentary but very easy read. It doesn't have the solutions, but the questions are easy enough to work out with no prior knowledge (other than perhaps some nonaxiomatic set theory).

Comment: Did you have look at other posts tagged [general-topology+book-recommendation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology+book-recommendation)? For example, this one seems rather similar: [Topology Exercises Books](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612851/topology-exercises-books),

Comment: There are many topology books with different approaches and focuses. Many of the older books (that are cheaper) focus on topics that you may not need. You can get better answers by explaining what you want to get out of your topology course.

Comment: Judging from my students turned-in work, virtually all of the problems from Munkres's "Topology" have solutions on-line in various fora.

Comment: @parsiad I love Mendelson's book. It's so short it's more like a pamphlet than a book, but it's quality over quantity. The dearth of problems and lack of solutions is a bummer, but still great overall.

Answer (score 9):

Munkres' topology book is quite standard. Although I don't think he has an official solutions manual, many solutions exist online.

Answer (score 8):

During my student years I used and liked [General Topology](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486434796.html) by Stephen Willard. It has a [solution manual](http://jianfeishen.weebly.com/uploads/4/7/2/6/4726705/general_topology.pdf) by Jianfei Shen.

Also interesting: [General Topology](https://archive.org/details/GeneralTopology) by John L. Kelley.

Answer (score 8):

you can read munkres it's a good book ,there are solutions online on http://dbfin.com/topology/munkres

Answer (score 5):

Elementary Topology Problem Textbook

O. Ya. Viro, O. A. Ivanov, N. Yu. Netsvetaev, V. M. Kharlamov

Great book, with many easy problems, and with basically everything solved at the end of each chapter.

Answer (score 3):

Take this alternative choice [Topology Without Tears](http://www.topologywithouttears.net/)

Comment: does this book has solutions.

Comment: @EM4, a little seek in the web gives that there are links to that kind of works

Answer (score 3):

[Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131848690) is a really neat book. The author explains concepts clearly and includes easy to follow proofs and theorems. Also, as the title suggests, there are some sections on the applications of Topology, including some cool stuff like Cosmology, Knots, Dynamical Systems and Chaos. You normally don't see that in the standard Topology textbook.

Comment: Nice nice, yeah, but it doesn't have a solution manual as the OP requested.

Answer (score 2):

My course used Introduction to Topology by Gamelin and Greene; [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Topology-Second-Edition-Mathematics/dp/0486406806](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486406806). It's a little bit harder then Munkres but doesn't beat around the bush! You need to know some non-trivial set theory tho before starting. It has some solutions/hints and cost almost nothing.

Comment: Are there any solutions for exercises online except the solutions the book itself? I find some of the "solutions" that Gamelin has are non-trivial.

Comment: @Ninja not as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

"Introduction to Topology" of Gamelin. Highly readable. It contains solutions of some selected problems at the end.

Comment: This is the same book which was already suggested in [another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1594306), right?

Comment: Yes, but at the time I posted my answerr, I didn't aware of it.

Comment: Are there any solutions for exercises online except the solutions the book itself? I find some of the "solutions" that Gamelin has are non-trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The best textbook in my opinion is Munkres' book.
It's a balance between rigour and simplicity.
You can find the solutions to the exercises everywere on internet.

Answer (score 1):

"Counterexamples in Topology" by Lynn Arthur Steen and J.A. Seebach

"According to the authors of this highly useful compendium, focusing on examples is an extremely effective method of involving undergraduate mathematics students in actual research. It is only as a result of pursuing the details of each example that students experience a significant increment in topological understanding. With that in mind, Professors Steen and Seebach have assembled 143 examples in this book, providing innumerable concrete illustrations of definitions, theorems, and general methods of proof. Far from presenting all relevant examples, however, the book instead provides a fruitful context in which to ask new questions and seek new answers.

Ranging from the familiar to the obscure, the examples are preceded by a succinct exposition of general topology and basic terminology and theory. Each example is treated as a whole, with a highly geometric exposition that helps readers comprehend the material."